# run git bash for windows in silent mode

Tags: c#, bash, git-bash

I am searching for a way to execute a bash shell script without displaying the terminal window. I start it from a c# program. The property ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow have no effect on suppress opening the bash terminal.

```
Process process = new Process {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                    FileName         = gitPath + "\\bash.exe",
                    Arguments        = "-c ./script.sh",
                    WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                    CreateNoWindow   = true} };
```

I hope the is maybe a parameter in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden does the trick!

```
Process process = new Process {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                    FileName         = gitPath + "\\bash.exe",
                    Arguments        = "-c ./script.sh",
                    WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                    CreateNoWindow   = true,
                    WindowStyle      = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden} };
```